# Forcing the UI Rendering after I performed an action in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am developing a drawing application in UWP and I have some blinking problems. If I can delay FPS, I suppose that the problem will be solved. How can I force the UI rendering after I performed an action in UWP? How can I delay UI rendering in UWP?
Could you please help me about that?

I can detail the problem as follows. There are two overlapped "SwapChainPanel", the user is drawing a stroke the on the topmost layer and then I am clearing stroke from the topmost layer when the user presses up the finger. After this process, I am drawing the strokes on the second layer. There is being a blink. I am using two swapchainpanel, one of the these panels is for the drawing, the other one is for showing. This is required for the application UI design. How can I solve this blinking problem?

Comment: "some blinking problems" is too generic...what are you drawing ? how ? it as nothing to do with fps : you are certainly doing something wrong because i never see any WPF app blinking... :-)

Comment: @GCamel Thanks, I have added some details about the problem.

Comment: Including a [mcve] would help.

Comment: WPF and UWP is not the same so please remove one of the tags to avoid confusion.

Comment: Maybe clear the stroke from the first layer after you draw it on the second layer.